# How do I set up a has many through for two different associations between the the same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship, rails-activerecord

I have two models, a `User` and a `Event`, and I would to set up two different associations between them.

I want:
- a user to have many hosted events
- a user to have many attended events
- an event to belong to one user (owner / creator)
- an event to belong to many users (attendees)

It's a has and belongs to many relationship for the attended event and just has many for the hosted events, I just don't know how to set it up properly / the rails way.

I know I'd need a users_attended_events table

I *think* that would be something like this on the `User` model

```
has_many :events, through: :hosted_events
has_many :events, through: :attended_events
```

But what would I do about the `Event`'s model?

I have:

```
belongs_to: user
alias_attribute :owner, :user
alias_attribute :creator, :user

has_many :users, through:???
```

this should be the users_attended_events table, so.. what would I put here? How do I name this "Attendees"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you need a has_many through association for users hosting events. Something like this should work sufficiently for that (in **user.rb**) if you have a `hosted_by_id` column on your `events` table:

```
has_many :hosted_events, class_name: "Event", foreign_key: "hosted_by_id"
```

For attending events assuming a join class with columns `attendee_id` and `event_id`:

```
class AttendeeEvent < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :event

end
```

You can add the following association to **user.rb**:

```
has_many :attendee_events, foreign_key: "attendee_id"
has_many :attended_events, through: :attendee_events, source: :event
```

The `source: :event` option indicates that the target objects for this association are found from the `event` association on the joining object.

The associations in **event.rb** are then:

```
belongs_to :hosted_by, class_name: "User"
has_many :attendee_events
has_many :attendees, through: :attendee_events
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the first has_many line in user.rb the `has_many :attendee_events`? symantically, I don't understand.

A user has many attended events. 
I understand that attendee_events is the join table / class. but I guess, I don't understand why the two has_manys need to be separated out.

Comment: also, would it be frowned upon by `the rails way` if I use `attendance` instead of attendee_event? (I know the rails convention is model1_model2)

Comment: actually, since I've renamed things attendee_events to attendances .. and I think that makes semantic sense. thanks!